# Instance and Static control-flow with inheritance and overriding/method-hiding

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, control-flow, method-hiding

I'm toying around with instance control flow and static control flow, notice the code below

```
class A {
    {
        m1();
    }
    A(){
        System.out.println("A constructor");
    }
    void m1(){
        System.out.println("A m1");
    }
}
public class Main extends A {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Main m = new Main();
    }
    void m1(){
        System.out.println("Main m1");
    }
}
```

The output for the code is:

Main m1

A constructor

I know this is because:
First, static blocks and variables were identified top-to-bottom parent-to-child, in this case there was just a `main()` that was static.
 Second, the static blocks and variable assignments are executed, so `main()`'s execution starts, and there is an attempt to create a new `Main` object.

 So third, the instance blocks and variables of parent class will be identified. Then they will be executed top-bottom. (After that the constructor of the parent class will run, then the instance blocks and variables of child class will be identified, following which they will be executed top-bottom and finally the child class' constructor will execute).

So the instance block inside A, calls `m1()`. Then, A's constructor executes. Finally, control flow is returned to `main()` and program terminates.

Now, the call to `m1()` from A invoked `m1()` of `Main`. However, had I made both the `m1()` methods static, everything else remaining same, the call to `m1()` from the instance block of A would then have invoked `m1()` of A.

I have two questions(Why? Purely for academic reasons, I'm still learning Java):

1. When both the `m1()` methods are non-static, is it possible to invoke A's m1() from the instance block of A? I tried doing a `this.m1()` but that still invoked Main's m1().(Why?)
2. When both the `m1()` methods are static, is it possible to invoke Main's m1() from the instance block of A? (I'm guessing no but I'm not certain).

   I know in the first case, it's overriding taking place, and in the second case it's method hiding. But I'm still not sure how to answer my questions based on that knowledge.

Comment: Try reading twice or thrice your own question you will be able to answer the question on your own.

Comment: Apparently, I couldn't.

Comment: `super.m1()` will call the non-overriden (local) method (i.e. from the superclass). `Main.m1()` will call specifically the (static) `m1()` method from `Main` while `A.m1()` will call `A`'s.

Comment: @Matthieu yes, your suggestion for my 2nd question works, as I realised a few moments ago. About the super.m1(), well that's what I thought as well, since the reference was that of Main, so super.m1() in the instance block of A should have called A's m1(), however replacing m1() with super.m1() causes an error. `error: cannot find symbol method m1()`

Comment: That's because `A` doesn't have a superclass (more precisely: only inherits `Object`). `super` may only be used when you *know* you overrode a method and want to call the "original" one (from the superclass you know).

Comment: @Matthieu Okay. So, what again was your suggestion? I want to call A's m1() from the instance block of class A, not do a super.m1() from class Main.

Comment: I'd suggest making the method `final` to prevent overriding it. I don't have anything to test now but it could also prevent you from defining an `m1()` method in `Main` though...

Comment: @Matthieu but that isn't my question at all, sorry. I'm trying to call m1() of A,  from the instance block of A, given that A's subclass overrides m1(). Furthermore, I expected that since this.m1() invoked Main's m1(), super.m1() should have invoked A's m1(), which didn't happen. This has nothing to do with implementation details or design like you're suggesting, this is an academic doubt. Hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: That's not possible (unless you start fiddling with reflection, which is definitely not recommended). The point of overriding methods is precisely to adapt a behavior to a new implementation (the subclass). The only option Java gives you is to make methods `final` to prevent overriding. You can't cherry-pick which method to call; if you need to, then make two different methods or change your design pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After compilation is done java 8 compiler your code looks like this:

```
 class A {
           A() {
              this.m1();  // at runtime this refers to Main class instance
              System.out.println("A constructor");
           }
        
           void m1() {
              System.out.println("A m1");
           }
        }

public class Main extends A {
     public Main() { }

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          Main m = new Main();
          m.m1();
       }
    
       void m1() {
          System.out.println("Main m1");
       }
    }
```

Now to answer your first question: No. You cannot unless you are creating an instance of A(actual object of A).

To your second question:
after making both m1's static compilation looks like this:

```
class A {
   A() {
      m1(); // resolves to A's m1
      System.out.println("A constructor");
   }

   static void m1() {
      System.out.println("A m1");
   }
}
public class Main extends A {
   public Main() {
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      new Main();
   }

   static void m1() {
      System.out.println("Main m1");
   }
}
```

Now no matter which instance(A or Main) you create you will see A's m1 excuted.

Comment: That was well explained. I was looking for a straightforward yes/no followed by an explanation. This does just that, perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

1.(When two methods are instance method) If you are inside the A (parent) class, if you call `m1()`; or `this.m1();` you will call the A version of the `m1()` method but if you are inside the main class (child), if you call `m1();` you will call the main version of m1 although if you call `super.m1();` you will  be calling the A version of m1 method.

2.(If the methods are static) you can call each version wherever you want, without and object of a class, for example, you can invoke main´s m1 method inside the A block with the following line `Main.m1(); // ClassName.StaticMethodName();`

Comment: My question was a direct contradtion to your first point. If you look at the code snippet I provided, I'm calling m1() from class A, yet class Main's m1() is being invoked. It appears your answer is incorrect, unless there's a misunderstanding?

Comment: If you use this.instanceMethod(); you will always call the method version of the class where it is contain or in the case there is an absence of an overriding it will call the parent version due to the dynamic blinding.

So if you are getting the Main´s version is because you are calling the method from the Main´s class, there is no other way in java, you can access the parent class method with the super.m1() as I have already tell you

Comment: please try running my code, and notice I'm calling m1() inside A, yet Main's m1() gets called.

Comment: Yes, it is something funny here, as there is no constructor defined by Main, the compiler just call super (of A). that is, when creating a Main, you are also creating an A, but you are using the static code of A as you are an instance of Main. So when you are calling m1 in the static block code of A, you are a Main instance indeed, so that why you receive the output of Main m1. 

It is is a little bit cumbersome to see it but just try to change Main m = new Main(); to A m = new A(); in the main class and you will see the difference.

Comment: This happens because you are calling an instance method within an static block of code and because java use dynamic blinding 
See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding

Comment: What? Okay now that is just plain wrong, sorry. I do not have any static blocks in my code. It is an instance blocks. Instance blocks and static blocks are different. And so, none of what you said applies or makes sense, I'm afraid.